# Extract text using css selector

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to extract specific text using a CSS selector. Here's a screenshot of the part that I would like to extract

[image]

I tried

```
div[id="Section3"]:first-child
```

but this doesn't return anything. I can't depend on locating the element by the text because I need to extract that text as shown.

This is the relevant HTML

```
<div class="ad24123fa4-c17c-4dc5-9aa5-ea007a8db30e-5" style="top:8px;left:218px;width:124px;height:31px;text-align:center;">
    <table width="113px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <span class="fcb900b29f-64d7-453d-babf-192e86f17d6f-7">نظامي</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The full HTML is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ys7itn33h1cg88y/FolderToTest.rar).

This is my try

```
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .FindElementByXPath("//span[text()='ãäÇÒá']")
            If ele Is Nothing Then sStatus = "äÙÇãí" Else sStatus = "ãäÇÒá"
        On Error GoTo 0
```

While inspecting the element I noticed that there is a hint of using $0 in the console .. Can this be useful?
[image]

As for the two possible texts "نظامي" and "منازل"

Comment: What does the HTML look like at that point?

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: That's some pretty unfriendly HTML for automation. I'm assuming you've stripped out a lot of the related HTML because those two tables are pretty empty. Are there any text labels around the desired text that you can use as an anchor? I can't read Arabic but something like... `First name: John` where you want the text 'John'?

Comment: I am using selenium for this part ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use xpath with multiple possible search values use the following syntax:

```
//*[text()='نظامي' or text()='منازل']
```

CSS selectors (that work for me):

```
driver.findElementByCss("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CrystalReportViewer1 div.ad071889d2-8e6f-4755-ad7d-c44ae0ea9fca-5 table span").text
```

which is an abbreviation of the full selector:

```
#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CrystalReportViewer1 > tbody > tr > td > div > div.crystalstyle > div.ad071889d2-8e6f-4755-ad7d-c44ae0ea9fca-5 > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > span
```

You can also index into table nodeList

```
Set matches = html.querySelectorAll("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CrystalReportViewer1 div.crystalstyle table")
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = matches.item(80).innerText
```

Otherwise:

Reading in from html file I can take the last index of the matches based on class selector. For selenium you would switch to:

```
driver.FindElementsByCss(".fc180999a8-04b5-46bc-bf86-f601317d19c8-7").count
```

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, matches As Object
    Dim fStream  As ADODB.Stream
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set fStream = New ADODB.Stream
    With fStream
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Output6.html"
        html.body.innerHTML = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With

    Set matches = html.querySelectorAll(".fc180999a8-04b5-46bc-bf86-f601317d19c8-7")

    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = matches.item(matches.Length - 1).innerText
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. As for .count I got 0 .. and the class '.fc180999a8-04b5-46bc-bf86-f601317d19c8-7' is not fixed, it changes each time .. Is the xpath will be easier?

Comment: There are two possible text. Is it possible to include both and check for the existing element for both of them? I have posted my try but doesn't work properly and I got incorrect results for the string variable

Comment: This is perfect `//*[text()='نظامي' or text()='منازل']` but is it possible to make it more specific. Thanks a lot for that solution

Comment: I mean to put some other anchors to refer to that part or around ... and have you seen the tip of $0? Is that may be useful?

Comment: When using `sStatus = .FindElementByXPath("//*[text()='نظامي' or text()='منازل']").Text` >> I tested on two cases and I got 'نظامي" for both cases !! ..

Comment: I was wrong about the last point ... I am so sorry .. Just need to make it specific for Span tag if possible

Comment: Thank you very much my tutor. I am very grateful for all this awesome help